# What Resources To Learn About AT89S52

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, industrial

Can anyone tell me about some books or sites for video tutorial which are specific to Atmel 89S52 because I googled and I am not getting any video tutorial,books or ppt except datasheet to learn about AT89S52 microcontroller.

In our college course instead of 8051 (which is usually tought) we have been tought about AT89S52 and from course point of view I am not getting any book or video tutorials all those tutorials on youtube which I found are related to projects made using AT89S52.

So, if anyone can suggest some links, it will be very helpful.
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

The Atmel AT89S52 is compatible with the Intel 8051 family, so any 8051 reference material should apply.  For any AT89S52-specific data, you should look for the Atmel Databook on that microcontroller.

Comment: I looked at the datasheet but it is very much not in brief and i want to understand the things in brief

Comment: Unfortunately, microcontrollers are very complex devices, so it will be difficult to find anything that explains them "in brief".  Perhaps you should look for info on basic microprocessor or CPU operation, as that is at the heart of a microcontroller.  When you have some understanding of the CPU function, then you can study the various peripheral devices in a microcontroller as you need to use them.  Don't get bogged down trying to understand the whole thing in one go.